# Select columns using a vector

Tags: r, list, rowsum

I am trying to create a new data frame with 2 columns: `var1` and `var2`, each one of them is the row sum of specific columns in data frame `sampData`.

```
library(dplyr)

sampData <-
  rnorm(260) %>%
  matrix(ncol = 26) %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  setNames(LETTERS)

var1 <- c("A", "B", "C")
var2 <- c("D", "E", "F", "G")
```

I know that I can select columns using `[]` and `c()`, like this:

```
sampData[ ,c("A","B")]
```

but when I try to generate and use that format from my vectors like this:

```
d1_ <-paste(var1, collapse=",")
d2_ <-paste(var2, collapse=",")

sampData[ ,d1_]
```

I get this error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(sampData, , d1_) : undefined columns selected
```

Which I also get if I try to calculate the `rowSums` -- which is what I am interested in getting.

```
data.frame(var1 = rowSums(sampData[ , d1_])
           , var2 = rowSums(sampData[ , d2_])
```

Comment: My recent edit switches over to using reproducible data (we don't have access to your sql databases) and clarifies where the error messages are arising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have managed to figure out what you are asking, but if I am wrong, let me know.

You are trying to select columns from `prep` that match the values in `l1` and `l2`, and sum across the rows, limited to the columns that matched each.

It is always better to provide reproducible data, here is some for this case (using `dplyr` to build it):

```
sampData <-
  rnorm(260) %>%
  matrix(ncol = 26) %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  setNames(LETTERS)

var1 <- c("A", "B", "C")
var2 <- c("D", "E", "F", "G")
```

Then, you don't need to concatenate the column indices at all -- just use the variable (or column, in your case) directly. Here, I have made the ID's letters and will match the letters. However, if your ID's are numeric, it will match that index (e.g., `3` will return the third column).

```
data.frame(
  var1sums = rowSums(sampData[, var1])
  , var2sums = rowSums(sampData[, var2])
)
```

Of note, `cat` returns `NULL` after printing to the screen. If you need to concatenate values, you will need to use `paste` (or similar), but that will **not** work for what you are trying to do here.

This question got me thinking about flexibility of such solutions, so here is an attempt using `dplyr` and `tidyr`, which yields effectively the same result. The difference is that this may provide more flexibility for variable selection or even downstream processing.

```
sampData %>%
  # add column for individual
  mutate(ind = 1:nrow(.)) %>%
  # convert data to long format
  gather("Variable", "Value", -ind) %>%
  # Set to group by the individual we added above
  group_by(ind) %>%
  # Calculate sums as desired
  summarise(
    var1sums = sum(Value[Variable %in% var1])
    , var2sums = sum(Value[Variable %in% var2])
  )
```

However, the real advantage would come if you had an *arbitrary number* (or just a large number generally) of sets of variables that you wanted to get the individual sums from. Instead of manually constructing every column you might be interested in, you can use standard evaluation (as opposed to non-standard) to automatically generate the columns based on a named list of vectors:

```
sampData %>%
  mutate(ind = 1:nrow(.)) %>%
  gather("Variable", "Value", -ind) %>%
  group_by(ind) %>%
  # Calculate one column for each vector in `varList`
  summarise_(
    .dots = lapply(varList, function(x){
      paste0("sum(Value[Variable %in% c('"
             , paste(x, collapse = "', '")
             , "')])")
    })
  )
```

Comment: Thank you, I have changed the last line to this DF3<-data.frame(
  var1sums = rowSums(prep[,d1_])
  , var2sums = rowSums(prep[, d2_])
) but i received the same error : Error in `[.data.frame`(prep, d1_) : undefined columns selected

Comment: You should not be using the output of `paste` at all in your column selection (which is where `d1_` and `d2_` came from). For your example, you should be using `new.variable1.v` and `new.variable2.v`

Comment: Glad it helped, see my edit for a potentially more general-case solution if you are interested. I am also going to take a crack at editing your question to clarify what it is you are trying to do.